# How do I create a valid json file from an API using pagenation in python?

Tags: python, json, api

I am trying to pull all the people from the Star Wars API into one valid json file.

The API limits the result set and all the 'people' span 9 sepaerate calls(i.e 'https://swapi.co/api/people/?page=1', 'https://swapi.co/api/people/?page=2', etc).

When I loop through the multiple requests, I end up with unvalid json as there is no comma delimiter between the documents and now starting and ending brackets.

Please help me solve what I am doing wrong in the call.

```
import requests
import json

for x in range(1,9):  
    response = requests.get("https://swapi.co/api/people/?page="+str(x))
    data = response.json()

    next_page = data["next"] 
    results = data["results"]

    for result in results:  
        with open('data.json', 'a') as outfile:
            json.dump(result, outfile)
print('Done!')
```

json file output:

```
{"name": "Luke Skywalker", "height": "172", "mass": "77", "hair_color": "blond", "skin_color": "fair", "eye_color": "blue", "birth_year": "19BBY", "gender": "male", "homeworld": "https://swapi.co/api/planets/1/", "films": ["https://swapi.co/api/films/2/", "https://swapi.co/api/films/6/", "https://swapi.co/api/films/3/", "https://swapi.co/api/films/1/", "https://swapi.co/api/films/7/"], "species": ["https://swapi.co/api/species/1/"], "vehicles": ["https://swapi.co/api/vehicles/14/", "https://swapi.co/api/vehicles/30/"], "starships": ["https://swapi.co/api/starships/12/", "https://swapi.co/api/starships/22/"], "created": "2014-12-09T13:50:51.644000Z", "edited": "2014-12-20T21:17:56.891000Z", "url": "https://swapi.co/api/people/1/"}{"name": "C-3PO", "height": "167", "mass": "75", "hair_color": "n/a", "skin_color": "gold", "eye_color": "yellow", "birth_year": "112BBY", "gender": "n/a", "homeworld": "https://swapi.co/api/planets/1/", "films": ["https://swapi.co/api/films/2/", "https://swapi.co/api/films/5/", "https://swapi.co/api/films/4/", "https://swapi.co/api/films/6/", "https://swapi.co/api/films/3/", "https://swapi.co/api/films/1/"], "species": ["https://swapi.co/api/species/2/"], "vehicles": [], "starships": [], "created": "2014-12-10T15:10:51.357000Z", "edited": "2014-12-20T21:17:50.309000Z", "url": "https://swapi.co/api/people/2/"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save your results into memory and then do just one `json.dump` will solve your problem:

```
import requests
import json

results = []
for x in range(1, 9):
    response = requests.get("https://swapi.co/api/people/?page="+str(x))
    data = response.json()

    next_page = data["next"]
    results.extend(data["results"])

with open('data.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(results, outfile)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of serializing as you go, append the data to a list and serialize it once when you reach the end.

```
all_results = []

for x in range(1,9):  
    response = requests.get("https://swapi.co/api/people/?page="+str(x))
    data = response.json()

    next_page = data["next"] 
    results = data["results"]
    all_results.extend(results)

with open('data.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(all_results, outfile)
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this solves your problem for missing commas

```
import requests
import json

for x in range(1,9):  
    response = requests.get("https://swapi.co/api/people/?page="+str(x))
    data = response.json()

    next_page = data["next"] 
    results = data["results"]

    res = ''
    for result in results:  
        temp = str(result) + ',' 
        res = res + temp 
    with open('data.json', 'a') as outfile:
      outfile.write(res)

print('Done!')
```

I have just converted 'result' variable  to string and appended it for each page. When the dictionaries for a single page ends it appends it to the file 'data.json'.